# Set document size as variable and compare it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was trying different ways to compare if cursor end position is bigger than 90% of the document total size it will set an element to 90% height.

menu opens when i drag a box on an element

```
menu.style.top = cursorY.toString() + 'px';
        let screenSize = ($(document).height === 90 + '%')
        if (cursorY.toString() === screenSize){
          menu.style.top = 90 + '%';
        }
```

If i use `cursorY.toString() !== screenSize` or `cursorY.toString() > screenSize` instead of **===** it will set the element to 90% as default instead of changing the having a dynamic position

```js
const button = document.getElementById('boundingBox');
const contextMenu = document.getElementById('cntnr')

document.getElementById('boundingBox').addEventListener('click', () => {
    if(contextMenu.style.display === "block") {
        contextMenu.style.display = "none"
    }
   else{
    contextMenu.style.display = "block"
   }
   // Button emulates bounding box higher than 90% of the document size
   
   /*bounding box is a draggable element and cursorY gets the last position of cursor and opens the menu with an event 
   */
   
   //I dont want my app to overflow the whole document i want the menu to show on 90%(on my app) or this case top === 80% if my cursorY position is higher than than 80%
   
   
   /*let screenSize = ($(document).height() === 90 + '%')
            if (cursorY.toString() === screenSize){
              contextMenu.style.top = 90 + '%';
            }
    */
})
```

```css
body{
  background-color: black;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#boundingBox{
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}
#cntnr{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid #F9F9F9;
    width: 150px;
    background: #f9f9f9;
    border-radius:4px;
    z-index: 5000;
    top: 80%;
}
```

```html
<button id="boundingBox">
    click to open context menu
</button>


<div class="context-menu-wrapper" id="contextMenuWrapper">
            <div id='cntnr'>
                <ul id='items'>
                <li>Fracture</li>
                <hr>
                <li>Cancel</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

edit: i've solved it with

```
        const screenSize = $(document).height(); //get's user screen size
        let menuLimit = screenSize - (screenSize/10); //set the limit to 90%
```

Comment: what is `$(document)` ?

Comment: trying to compare strings as numbers?

Comment: document is the whole html document

Comment: I mean what is $().....

Comment: It's jQuery selecting the document

Comment: $(document) it is the html document

Comment: How can I say this in another way..... What is `$`.....

Comment: It is a Jquery selector

Comment: that dollar sign is just a function name it's the selector in jQuery

Comment: Well jQuery has no height property, height is a method. https://api.jquery.com/height/ So you are checking to see if a function is equal to a string.

Comment: @SaymoinSam that is an assumption without the OP stating it, OP just stated it so we can say it is.

Comment: What is `cursorY`? We need more context.

Comment: CursorY is cursor position on Y axis

Comment: What is it exactly, I do not want to guess..... Show some code

Comment: Alright, let me to post it in jsfiddle

Comment: @JoseMoreno you can post a live example using Stack snippets, you don't need JSfiddle for that

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qfhscotd/8/ hope this help to understand my problem

Comment: I also added the snippet, thanks for the advice